# Fetch works on PC live server in VS Code but not working on hosting server

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I have a problem, that I have simple website with many HTML webpages and and one Script file, so in this script file I have code this:

```
fetch("/aside/aside.html")
.then(response => {
  return response.text()
})
.then(data => {
  document.getElementById("aside_buttons").innerHTML = data;
});
```

After each page loads it replace information in aside_buttons place, all works fine, but when I put my webpage on the server it does not replace aside_buttons place.

Does anybody know what is wrong with it?

My project that works on PC VS Code live server: [project with all files](https://failiem.lv/u/2nz8feyvs)

and all projects on host: [on host website](https://www.jcp.lv)

Try to click buttons on aside right place they have old information, and fetch replaces it, all works on pc if your test project, but on host [www.jcp.lv](http://www.jcp.lv) is not working.

Comment: Have a look in developer tools at the networking tab, make sure the requests are heading to the correct destination.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: all works fine when i am testing on home pc, but not working when i put project in hosting

Comment: Then please share more details. What does "not working" mean? Is the request blocked? Does it return something different?

Comment: my project on cloud please look, test, mybe you can see more its script file.. https://failiem.lv/u/2nz8feyvs

Comment: and website on host: www.jcp.lv

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. You need to do your own debugging (the browser developer tools are a good place to start) and report the results.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! When I used the following line and all worked fine.

```js
$( "#aside_buttons" ).load( "/aside/aside.html");
```